# How can i get total view count of a product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-view, reports

I would like to load product view hit count for a specific product , i found that Magento database stores some counting in table e.g.

```
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
```

How can I load this value for showing in frontend?  Do I need to set date range on it?

#### Updates:

I try to use:

```
$collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Product\Viewed\Collection')
```

to get the collection according to what it can be done on Magento 1.

```
Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Product\Viewed\Collection
```

is extending:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
```

which is extending:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

where there is a method `setDateRange()`, but when I call it, it shows error "**unknown method**". Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any product, you can set the product_id to the report collection

```
/**
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getProductCount($id)
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product
     */
    //Get Object Manager Instance
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    //Load product by product id
    $productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $productcollection->setProductAttributeSetId($productObj->getAttributeSetId());
    $prodData = $productcollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

    if (count($prodData) > 0) {
        foreach ($prodData as $product) {
            if ($product['entity_id'] == $id) {
                return (int) $product['views'];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then in your template phtml , use it by

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Mymodule\Viewcount\Block\Viewcount');
                                echo $blockObj->getProductCount($_product->getId());
```

Comment: Thanks, very uncomplicated solution that worked out-of-the-box even though direct use of ObjectManager is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show product view of current product in product view page then,

i have simple and easy sollution, and you can place it in PHTML file,

```
/*get current product*/
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

/*get product view*/
$id = $product->getId();
$productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productcollection->setProductAttributeSetId($productObj->getAttributeSetId());
$prodData = $productcollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

if (count($prodData) > 0) {
    foreach ($prodData as $_product) {
        if ($_product['entity_id'] == $id) {
            echo (int) $_product['views'];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You @leo .
work like a magic Thanks

Answer By Sandip Patel Suggested and help From leo.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the Magento2 version of the code that MagickVishal posted.

```
class ProductViewCount extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView { 
 /**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_productRepo;


/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
protected $_prodCollection;


/**
 * ProductViewCount constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepo
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils
 * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepo,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productRepo = $productRepo;
    $this->_prodCollection = $prodCollection;
    $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
    parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $data);
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getProductCount($id)
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product
     */
    $prodData = $this->_prodCollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

    if (count($prodData) > 0) {
        foreach ($prodData as $product) {
            if ($product['entity_id'] == $id) {
                return (int) $product['views'];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}}
```

If you want to add a date range for the views, yo would add them to the addViewsCount() function:  addViewsCount($from, $to).