# Magento 2 - Get View count for the product

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

Below is my code following [the post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127607/how-can-i-get-total-view-count-of-a-product-in-magento2).

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView;

class ProductViewCount extends AbstractView
{ 
    /**
    * @var CollectionFactory
    */
    protected $_productRepo;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $_prodCollection;


    /**
     * ProductViewCount constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepo
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepo,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productRepo = $productRepo;
        $this->_prodCollection = $prodCollection;
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProductViewCount()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $productId = $_product->getId();
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product
         */
        $prodData = $this->_prodCollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

        if (count($prodData) > 0) {
            foreach ($prodData as $product) {
                if ($product['entity_id'] == $productId) {
                    return (int) $product['views'];
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

In the above code, `$prodData = $this->_prodCollection->addViewsCount()->getData();` always return an empty array. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the product attribute set id before you do the selection, like this:

```
$yourAttributeSet = 15; // or other
$prodData = $this->_prodCollection->setProductAttributeSetId($yourAttributeSet)->addViewsCount()->getData();
```

becouse in the `addViewsCount` method only one attribute set id is available:

```
$this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['report_table_views' => $this->getTable('report_event')],
        ['views' => 'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)']
    )->join(
        ['e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()],
        $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.attribute_set_id = ?',
            $this->getProductAttributeSetId()
        )
    )->where(
        'report_table_views.event_type_id = ?',
        $productViewEvent
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    )->order(
        'views ' . self::SORT_ORDER_DESC
    )->having(
        'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > ?',
        0
    );
```

I think there is no way to select the data using this collection for many attribute sets.

Result sql looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`,
  `e`.*
FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views`
  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.attribute_set_id = '4'
WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1)
GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`
HAVING (COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0)
ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

As you can see the default attribute set is set to 4 (default). If we remove this condition from the select we can get statistics for the all of products:

```
SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`,
  `e`.*
FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views`
  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id
WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1)
GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`
HAVING (COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0)
ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

Result:

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| views | entity_id | attribute_set_id | type_id      | sku     | has_options | required_options | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    33 |         1 |               15 | simple       | 24-MB01 |           0 |                0 | 2016-11-22 08:43:50 | 2016-11-22 08:43:50 |
|     3 |         3 |               15 | simple       | 24-MB03 |           0 |                0 | 2016-11-22 08:43:50 | 2016-11-22 08:43:50 |
|     1 |       611 |                9 | configurable | MS07    |           1 |                0 | 2016-11-22 08:44:24 | 2016-11-22 08:44:24 |
|     1 |       846 |               10 | configurable | MP09    |           1 |                0 | 2016-11-22 08:44:31 | 2016-11-22 08:44:31 |
|     1 |        20 |               11 | simple       | 24-UG01 |           0 |                0 | 2016-11-22 08:43:53 | 2016-11-22 08:43:53 |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you wish to get the same result you should write your own filter-method for the collection, like this (just remove the attribute set condition):

```
public function addViewsCount($from = '', $to = '')
{
    /**
     * Getting event type id for catalog_product_view event
     */
    $eventTypes = $this->_eventTypeFactory->create()->getCollection();
    foreach ($eventTypes as $eventType) {
        if ($eventType->getEventName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $productViewEvent = (int)$eventType->getId();
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['report_table_views' => $this->getTable('report_event')],
        ['views' => 'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)']
    )->join(
        ['e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()],
        'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id'
    )->where(
        'report_table_views.event_type_id = ?',
        $productViewEvent
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    )->order(
        'views ' . self::SORT_ORDER_DESC
    )->having(
        'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > ?',
        0
    );

    if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
        $this->getSelect()->where('logged_at >= ?', $from)->where('logged_at <= ?', $to);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Result in the debug window:

[image: Result in the debug window]

Example of the code:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $prodCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Type\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $eventTypeCollectionFactory;

/**
 * Channels constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $prodCollectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Type\CollectionFactory $eventTypeCollectionFactory
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $prodCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Type\CollectionFactory $eventTypeCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->eventTypeCollectionFactory = $eventTypeCollectionFactory;
    $this->prodCollectionFactory = $prodCollectionFactory;
}

/**
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $to
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function getReportData($from = '', $to = '')
{
    /** @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $prodCollection */
    $prodCollection = $this->prodCollectionFactory->create();
    /** @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Type\Collection $eventTypeCollection */
    $eventTypeCollection = $this->eventTypeCollectionFactory->create();
    $catalogProductViewFilter = $eventTypeCollection->addFieldToFilter('event_name', 'catalog_product_view')->getFirstItem();
    if ($catalogProductViewFilter->getData('event_type_id')) {
        $productViewEvent = $catalogProductViewFilter->getData('event_type_id');
    } else {
        throw new Exception(__('Unknown event: catalog_product_view'));
    }

    $prodCollection->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['report_table_views' => $prodCollection->getTable('report_event')],
        ['views' => 'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)']
    )->join(
        ['e' => $prodCollection->getProductEntityTableName()],
        'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id'
    )->where(
        'report_table_views.event_type_id = ?',
        $productViewEvent
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    )->order(
        'views ' . \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC
    )->having(
        'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > ?',
        0
    );

    if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
        $prodCollection->getSelect()->where('logged_at >= ?', $from)->where('logged_at <= ?', $to);
    }

    $prodData = $prodCollection->getData();

    return $prodData;
}
```

Comment: Could you share more specific how you setup xdebug ? Your current  webserver run with xdebug in local dev enviroment

Comment: @mrtuvn you can share me your environment. I will share you.

Comment: Hi Khoa i am using ubuntu16.10 with apache for local but can't setup xdebug work with phpstorm. Plan to setup docker include xdebug