# Get product views in Controller

Tags: magento2, product, controllers, helper

If anyone could help me.

My curent value that I get is '0' in my controller:

```
   foreach($productCollection  as $product)     
   {
        $_helper_views =$this->helper_views->getProductCount($id);
   }
```

and in my helper:

```
    public function getProductCount($id)
    {

    // @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product


    $prodData = $this->_prodCollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

    if (count($prodData) > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($prodData as $product) 
        {
            if ($product['entity_id'] == $id) 
            {
                 return (int) $product['views'];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and Yes this product have views. I checked in `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly` and `report_viewed_product_aggregated_weekly` tables.

When I change return to:

return $prodData;

I get full array of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get proper value

I change in helper return to:

```
return $prodData;
```

and in Controller:

```
$_helper_views =$this->helper_views->getProductCount($product['entity_id']);
```

I'm also using different construct than [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127607/how-can-i-get-total-view-count-of-a-product-in-magento2/161156#161156) so I will later paste full code of my helper that's works on Magento 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the **product_id** to the report collection

```
public function getProductCount($id)
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product
     */
    //Get Object Manager Instance
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    //Load product by product id
    $productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $productcollection->setProductAttributeSetId($productObj->getAttributeSetId());
    $prodData = $productcollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

    if (count($prodData) > 0) {
        foreach ($prodData as $product) {
            if ($product['entity_id'] == $id) {
                return (int) $product['views'];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**You can Apply This Login Your Code**

[reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161156/72911)

Comment: I think I checked this and had the same result. Should I put this in helper? I will try one more time.

Comment: yes put in helper and check

Comment: its return 0 o whatever i put in return.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I just change my helper function to your from this link.

Comment: This function is actually doing same thing like mine, but mine is  without objectmanager

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm checking result in controller not in helper. I think something is wrong with controller part.

Comment: check value of $proData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93918/discussion-between-bartzalas-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: When I add this return $prodData; I get full array with data.